# Remove item from Woocommerce minicart using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce and I'm trying to remove item from the mini cart using ajax.

By looking at woocommerce `minicart.php` file I have found the relevant functionality to removing item:

```
<?php
echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
    'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
    sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" class="remove1" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
        esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
        esc_attr__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
        esc_attr( $product_id ),
        esc_attr( $cart_item_key ),
        esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
    ),
    $cart_item_key
);
?>
```

But I can't figure out how to run the command through ajax instead of refreshing the page. I have tried to modify code I found about adding to cart using ajax.

Didn't work, the page still refreshes.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove1', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $thisbutton = $(this),
        $form = $thisbutton.closest('form.cart'),
        id = $thisbutton.val(),
        product_qty = $form.find('input[name=quantity]').val() || 1,
        product_id = $form.find('input[name=product_id]').val() || id,
        variation_id = $form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val() || 0;

var data = {
    action: 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed',
    product_id: product_id,
    product_sku: '',
    quantity: product_qty,
    variation_id: variation_id,
};


$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url, // What params should I use?
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function (response) {
        $thisbutton.removeClass('added').addClass('loading');
    },
    complete: function (response) {
        $thisbutton.addClass('added').removeClass('loading');
    },
    success: function (response) {

        if (response.error && response.product_url) {
            window.location = response.product_url;
            return;
        }
    },
});
});
```

`functions.php`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_remove_cart_item', 'update_cart', 10, 2 );

function update_cart(){
  //What to do here?
}
```

No debugging errors.

Few important things I haven't found information online for:

- Which ajax url `url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url` should I use to remove item from mini cart?
- How to handle the data transferred from the ajax to `functions.php`?

How can I remove item from Woocommerce mini cart using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please check your WooCommerce settings to see if Ajax enables the add-to-cart button. If not, Enable it from the admin panel. Check out the screenshot [click here to see the screenshot of admin panel setting for ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeTUj.png)

Then try to remove the product from the cart.